# Am I really lucky?

Tags: riddle

Some considered me lucky, others not

Turn me sideways,  I can give you endless lot

Turn me upside down, I can give you the same pot

But be careful with that, I might lose oxygen and rot

**Hint 1**

> I look like 20 but I'm younger than you thought

What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are

> The number 8

Turned sideways it's

> Infinity

Upside down it's

> Also 8

I might lose oxygen and rot:

> Oxygen's atomic number is 8

Not sure about the hint

Comment: correct! easy riddle lol. Regarding hint, 20:00 is 8pm. :)

Comment: Ah, that's clever (and incredibly obvious in retrospect). Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

I know this was already answered, but I think the answer could also be a penny.

Comment: interesting. how would endless lot fit in?

Comment: Please expand your answer to explain how it fits all the clues. I'm curious to see what you're thinking. Refer to the accepted answer for an example.

Comment: Some people believe finding a penny head face up is lucky. Turned on its side it is round and endless. Upsidedown it could be lucky if flipped over, but oxygen corrodes the metal and can deface the coin over time, which also contributes to how old it looks, thus appearing 20 when its only 8.